# Why this query works in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

For instance, I have this JSON inject

```
{
    "insert": "2023-12-08T09:49:00"
}
```

It is String

I have sent this query here

```
db.example.find({ "insert" : { "$gt" : "2023-12-08T09:48:00.000Z", "$lt" : "2023-12-08T10:23:38" } })
```

How is possible that it works? I couldn't find any implicit conversion between String to UTCdate in docs.

I know this field must be a Date for best practices, but that got me curious if there any kind of explanation.

Comment: Because MongoDB compares strings as binary: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#strings. It is not converting to Date/Timestamp to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because it's doing a String comparison between two Strings. One of the many advantages of having dates in UTC-ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. Of course, this is not recommended for dates since string comparisons are much much slower than datetime comparisons, since those are effectively numbers (floating point).

So the parts that make a date *bigger* are to the left and also blends well with string comparison.

Example: Like `"aaa"` < `"bbb"`, same goes for `"2022"` < `"2023"`. It's just character-by-character comparison.

The string "2023-12-08T**0**9:49:00" is less than the string "2023-12-08T**1**0:23:38" - from left to right in each string, they are equal until `0` < `1`. It just happens to also look like a meaningful date format to humans.

Where things go wrong is if you tried to compare datetimes with different timezones, then it's just treated as a string and it wouldn't work correctly.

The datetime `2023-12-08T09:49:00+0800` > `2023-12-08T10:23:38+0100` (note the timezone specified after +/-). But as strings, it would say that the first < the second since no *meaning* or actual value is extracted from the timezone specification.

Btw, this behaviour of ISO format dates when stored-as-strings occurs in nearly **all programming languages**, since it's just string comparison. <sub>(Can't think of any where strings don't behave like this.)</sub>

---

Btw, if your document had that as a *real date* and not a string looking like a date, it would have the `$date` part, and always UTC in Mongo:

```js
{
  "insert": {
    "$date": "2023-12-08T09:49:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, this behaviour of dates when treated as strings occurs in nearly _all_ programming languages. It's also the best way to name folders, files, etc. if there is a date/time/datetime info since they would sort in a consistent order with their name, ascending or descending.

Comment: String `2023-12-08T09:49:00Z0800` is wrong. According ISO-8601 it must be `2023-12-08T09:49:00+0800`, `2023-12-08T09:49:00+08:00`,  `2023-12-08T09:49:00-0800` or `2023-12-08T09:49:00-08:00` `Z` is just an abbreviation for `+0000` (or `-0000`)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks, good catch! Fixed. Haven't use the +/- tz in so long.